# Initializing an empty file value in Elm

Tags: elm

I am using Elm (0.18) and imported simonh1000's [FileReader](https://github.com/simonh1000/file-reader) library.  To store a file value, we use the following type:

```
import Json.Decode as Json exposing (Decoder, Value)
...
{-| An ArrayBuffer is a Elm Json Value.
-}
type alias FileContentArrayBuffer =
    Value
```

I want to initialize my model with an empty placeholder.  I do this as follows:

```
type alias Model = 
  {
     username : String
   , filecontent: FileContentArrayBuffer
  }

initialModel : Model
initialModel = 
  {
     username = "mark"
   , filecontent = Nothing
  }
```

But the compiler gives me this error:

```
The type annotation for `initialModel` says it is a:

    Model

But the definition (shown above) is a:

    { username : String
    , filecontent : Maybe a
    }
```

Comment: What is the definition of `Model`? Also, are you trying to pass `init` to [`Html.program`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0/Html#program) which expects `init` to be of type `(model, Cmd msg)`?

Comment: @ChadGilbert the model definition includes `, emptyNewDesiredType  : MyNewDesiredType `.  Also,  `init` is just a model that's been initialized.  I'll update this to avoid the ambiguity.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "something empty"? Is there a json value that makes more sense for your domain than redefining your model to include `emptyNewDesiredType : Maybe MyNewDesiredType`?

Comment: My impression is that if `Value` refers to a Json object, then I would want to initialize that model item with the elm equivalent of javascript's `{}` empty json.  `emptyNewDesiredType ` must always have a json value, so I'd like to start it with empty json.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Elm is statically typed, it needs to know exactly the type of your JSON. In JavaScript, you can expand an object and add properties dynamically, but not in Elm. Type `Maybe a` gives you the safety that `Json.Decode` may not succeed, so it will return `Nothing` or `Just value` otherwise. You can then use pattern matching to see if `emptyNewDesiredType` has a value.

Comment: In that case, the specifics on my type may actually matter.  I am trying to encode a file using simonh1000's FileReader: https://github.com/simonh1000/file-reader/blob/master/src/FileReader.elm.  The value in question is `type alias FileContentArrayBuffer =
    Value`

Comment: Can you use the type directly? `type alias Model = 
  {
     emptyString : String
   , emptyInt : Int
   , emptyNewDesiredType : FileContentArrayBuffer
  }`? That would give you the buffer on which you can extract values using `decodeString`, `decodeInt` etc. https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/json.html

Comment: Saw your edit. Use `initialModel = 
  {
     username = "mark"
   , filecontent = Nothing
  }` to initialize it and change type to `type alias Model = 
  {
     username : String
   , filecontent: Maybe FileContentArrayBuffer
  }`. This is because the initialization will have empty content, which asks for `Maybe` type.

Comment: @TomislavMarkovski Tried that.  See the new edit.

Comment: I editted my comment, type must reflect the optional `Maybe` as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [`Json.Decode.Value`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Json-Decode#Value) is an alias for [`Json.Encode.Value`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Json-Encode#Value), if you really want to initialize a `Value` type as a JSON `{}`, you can do the following:

```
filecontent = Json.Encode.object []
```

However, I think in your case, it makes more sense to refactor to a `Maybe FileContentArrayBuffer` field type, since, what would you do with an `Value` type that decodes to `{}` anyway? A `Nothing` value definitely seems more fitting and idiomatic.