# Reading a FileReader type with a Maybe in elm

Tags: elm

(This is related to [Initializing an empty file value in Elm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47541291/initializing-an-empty-file-value-in-elm) )

I am using Elm (0.18) and imported simonh1000's [FileReader](https://github.com/simonh1000/file-reader) library. To store a file value, we use the following json type:

```
type alias FileContentArrayBuffer =
    Value
```

and I structure my model thusly:

```
type alias Model = 
  {
     username : String
   , filecontent: Maybe FileContentArrayBuffer
  }

initialModel : Model
initialModel = 
  {
     username = "mark"
   , filecontent = Nothing
  }
```

When a file is dropped into place, `getFileContents` is called.  The relevant functions and msg's are as follows:

```
getFileContents : NativeFile -> Cmd Msg
getFileContents nf =
    FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer nf.blob
        |> Task.attempt OnFileContent



type Msg
...
    | OnFileContent (Result FileReader.Error (Maybe FileContentArrayBuffer))



update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
...
        OnFileContent res ->
            case res of
                Ok (Just filecontent) ->
                    ( { model | filecontent = filecontent }, Cmd.none )

                Ok Nothing ->
                    Debug.crash "No Content"

                Err err ->
                    Debug.crash (toString err)
```

When I compile I get this error:

```
The right side of (|>) is causing a type mismatch.

56|     FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer nf.blob
57|>        |> Task.attempt OnFileContent

(|>) is expecting the right side to be a:

    Task.Task FileReader.Error FileReader.FileContentArrayBuffer -> a

But the right side is:

    Task.Task FileReader.Error (Maybe FileReader.FileContentArrayBuffer)
    -> Cmd Msg
```

Not sure why, given that I have included the `Maybe` in my Type and provided cases.  Any ideas?

Comment: as Chad notes, .readAsArrayBuffer returns a Task Error ArrayBuffer, so your Maybe is getting in the way and needs to be added later

Answer (score 1):

If you define `Msg` like this instead:

```
type Msg
...
    | OnFileContent (Result FileReader.Error FileContentArrayBuffer)
```

Then your update case can set the file value when successful or set to Nothing in failure:

```
    OnFileContent res ->
        case res of
            Ok filecontent ->
                ( { model | filecontent = Just filecontent }, Cmd.none )

            Err err ->
                ( { model | filecontent = Nothing }, Cmd.none )
```

Note that Debug.crash should be avoided at all costs. It really is just there for temporary debugging. It would be better perhaps to add an error message property on your model to notify the user of a problem.